# Returning another column from a max() per group row in SQL

Tags: sql-server

Table 1:

```
ITEMS  [ID, PRODUCT_ID, RUN_ID, NAME, LOCATION, LAST_MODIFIED]
```

I need a query to group total items by `Product_ID` and `Run_ID`.

Like so:

```
Select Product_ID, Run_ID, Count(ID) 
FROM ITEMS
Group by Product_ID, Run_ID
```

But I also need the `Location` for the `max(last_modified)` (the most recent) item in each group returned.

So in essence I need to get the max for one column but return another for that row.

Comment: What if there are multiple rows for a product/run with the same maximum last_modified?

Comment: I still only need one

Comment: Yeah but which one?  Also, Felix's revised suggestion below will give you 2 rows in that situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using [**window functions**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx), `ROW_NUMBER` and `COUNT OVER`:

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        cnt = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Product_ID, Run_ID),
        rn  = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Product_ID, Run_ID ORDER BY last_modified DESC)
    FROM ITEMS
)
SELECT
    Product_ID, Run_ID, cnt, Location
FROM Cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

---

Using `JOIN`:

```
SELECT
    t.Product_ID, t.Run_ID, t.cnt, i.Location
FROM (
    SELECT 
        Product_ID, Run_ID, Count(ID) AS cnt, MAX(last_modified) AS max_last_modified
    FROM ITEMS
    GROUP BY Product_ID, Run_ID
)t
INNER JOIN Items i
    ON t.Product_ID = i.Product_ID
    AND t.Run_ID = i.Run_ID
    AND t.max_last_modified = i.last_mdified
```

Comment: Although I am using SQL Server underneath it all, I need a more platform neutral sql statement